# Tips for a CFG for given L

Tags: context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

So my given **L = {(a^m)(b^n)(c^k)|m,n,k >= 0, and either m=k, n=k, or m=n}**

The part I'm finding tricky is the final rule where either **m=k, n=k, or m=n**. I can't exactly figure out a way to get that into a rule on the CFG. Regarding the first portion where **(a^m)(b^n)(c^k)** I believe this reads as just a ordered series of a's, b's, and c's. To look of the form: **aaaaabbbbbccccc**

```
S0 = a|aS0|aS1|Epsilon
S1 = b|bS1|bS2|Epsilon
S2 = c|cS2|Epsilon
```

Like I said, I think the above attempt I made covers the initial form, but doesn't translate the given rule.

Something I was thinking is that I can structure it in such a way that a&b, or b&c are added in unison. Something I was thinking to do this might be:

```
S1 = aS1b
```

This way when we put **aS1b** in **S1**, we see that our **a's** and **b's** grow equivalently: **aaaS1bbb** meaning **m** & **n** may be equal. The thing I can't figure out is how to make sure that this is implemented in the grammar. Having it this way makes it optional, but not necessary.

Any ideas or tips to riddling this one out?

Comment: There are three conditions. Implement each one separately.

Comment: That's just it. I know they're conditions and have to be implemented separate, but I can't see a means to do it. Given, I'm new to CFG's.

Comment: If L and M are languages (or start symbols in two grammars) and then I define S -> L ; S -> M. Now what is the language S in terms of L and M?